# CSS IE gradient not going to bottom of page

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hi I checked my website on IE 8 and found that the gradient code I put doesn't fill the whole page when there is no element going to the bottom of the page. The gradient works, but just not to the very bottom of the browser when maximized. I put in

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#01aef0', endColorstr='#9bd5eb', GradientType=0); zoom:1;
```

I tried using zoom:1; but it didn't work :C

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: which part in HTML would you like to see?

Comment: try `height` or `min-height` set to `100%` for `html, body, #wrap`

Comment: @nuk11888 Well, I would mostly like to see the part of the HTML that this applies to, and the HTML around it, specifically if this part is a child of anything else.

Comment: @Petr Marek Thanks the 'min-height' set to '100%' did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document doesn't stretch to the whole viewport.

`min-height` and/or `height` set to `100%` for `html, body, #wrap` makes sure that the whole viewport is filled.